# Minimum CircleCI 2 config.yml to get project using Elm and Rails to run successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, elm, circleci, circleci-2.0

My Selenium webdriver/Chromium Rspec (browser) tests are failing on pages that have Elm apps in them because the Elm generated JS seems to exist but is not running. I can see the path to the generated `.js` file. I did the reported CPU hack change using `libconfsyscpus` but still tests are failing. I've tried upping the timeout but it's taking so long that perhaps the CPU hack is different on CircleCI 2, or I missed something. My tests pass rather quickly on CircleCI 1 leading me to believe that:

1. I screwed up the `libconfsyscpus` config hack somehow
2. Perhaps I've neglected to include something in this docker based CircleCI 2 setup

Can someone share their CircleCI 2 config that can run Ruby, JavaScript, and Elm?

Comment: It would be better for you to share your config, and what problem you are running into specifically. If these are browser tests, can you run them in an SSH session so you can take a screenshot? Selenium should be able to do that for you.